# Join tables and see the count of categories in each category name in laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Excuse me want to ask. I'm sorry in advance if my language is not neat.

I have a `category` table with columns:

- id (pk)
- name
- and others

I have a `post` table with columns:

- id (pk)
- category_id(fk)
- and others

I want to count the number of posts from each category along with the category name in laravel 8.

This is my jQuery but it's incorrect:

```
$categ = DB::table('posts')
 ->select('category_id', 'categories.id', DB::raw('count(posts.id) as total_product'))
 ->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
 ->groupBy('posts.category_id')
 ->get();
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are willing to use Eloquent, the answer would be much simple.

> Post would be a model for posts table
>
> Category would be a model for categories table
>
> there would be one-to-one or any other relationship as per
> requirements between models

Let's say there is a one-to-many relationship between **Category** and **Post** model
This can be achieved by adding a function in your **Category** model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

then you can use something like...

```
Category::withCount('posts')->get()
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, it worked
but i have another question, so the question i did above really can't be done, sir? because I managed to do that query on the sql workbench

Comment: That can be done, even your code seems fine too, probably some typo issue. And Query Builder is almost 0.5% faster than eloquent. But eloquent comes with some set of security concepts such as mass assignment protection, DB injection, and different attributes as hidden or casting. You are not really being truly benefited from Laravel if not using eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you are using wrong table names in the query or may be have put the wrong table name in the question.

Let say your post table name is **posts** and categories table is **categories**, then your query should be:

```
$categ = DB::table('posts')
 ->select('categories.id', "categories.name", DB::raw("count(posts.id) as total_product"))
 ->join('categories, "posts.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
 ->groupBy('posts.category_id')
 ->get();
```

Please note - Make sure to replace the table names with your tables.

If you are using this for one time load, then you can use the model relationship as well to get the complete information without creating a custom query.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

You can have category to post relation.
Say you have Models Category and Post, then you can have below relation in Category model.

```
public function posts(){
 return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

And then in your code you can use `$category->posts` to get collection of posts for the category and can use `$category->posts->count()` to get the count of posts for the category.